# Flutter: Changing color of status bar when using Get.changeTheme()

Tags: flutter, statusbar, flutter-getx, theme-daynight

I am looking for a way to change the appearance of the status bar when changing my theme using **GetX**'s `Get.changeTheme()` utility function.

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      theme: lightTheme(),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () => {
                      Get.changeTheme(
                          Get.isDarkMode ? lightTheme() : darkTheme())
                    },
                child: Text('Change Theme'))));
  }
}

ThemeData darkTheme() {
  return ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[900]);
}

ThemeData lightTheme() {
  return ThemeData.light().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white);
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to change the color of the status bar when the "Change Theme" button is pressed (s. screenshot).

[image: Dark mode]

I have looked into the documentation of `ThemeData` but there seems to be no property which I could add to my `darkTheme()`in order to change the color of the text in the status bar to white. I am also aware of

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.white
));
```

But I do not know where to put this piece of code in the **GetX** architecture of my code, as including it within the `main()` method will not allow me to swop themes afterwards. I am also not planning on using `AppBar()` which would let me change the `brightness` property simply to achieve the desired outcome.

I am happy for any hints and advice!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the routingCallback function inside the GetMaterialApp widget so that you can change the status bar according to your app's routing.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      theme: lightTheme(),
      home: MyHomePage(),
      // Add this function to GetMaterialApp Widget
      routingCallback: (value) {
         // Here you can check which screen your app is currently on
         if(value.current == '/home'){
           SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
             statusBarColor: Colors.white
           ));
          }
             
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () => {
                      Get.changeTheme(
                          Get.isDarkMode ? lightTheme() : darkTheme())
                    },
                child: Text('Change Theme'))));
  }
}

ThemeData darkTheme() {
  return ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[900]);
}

ThemeData lightTheme() {
  return ThemeData.light().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white);
}
```

Comment: This one works only on Android...